# How to send a C# SOAP response to SoapUI before closing the web service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, soapui

The web service receives a SOAP request from SoapUI, parses it and records to a log. Here's the XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="localhost">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:HTTPWebService>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <loc:input>Data1</loc:input>
         <payload>Data1</payload>
      </loc:HTTPWebService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I would like the web service to do is to respond with a simple string i.e "OK" back to SoapUI and after the message has been sent record the time when the response was sent. Currently the only way I'm able to send a response is by returning the string when the web service closes. Here's an example of what I've been searching for:

```
   public void sendReply()
        {
            //Do stuff and send the string
            //Write to a log after the response has been sent
        }
```

The log part is done but I can't get the sending bit to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is log the time right before you return a value. The only way I've seen for services to continue processing after they send a response is to create another thread for it, which wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: That's what I thought but I was hoping there would be a better way around this. I'll do as suggested, thanks.